# How to enable DHCP con Oracle VM VirtualBox server

Tags: 14.04, maas

My scenario is:

Ubuntu Server 14 in a virtual machine created with Oracle VM VirtualBox

At the time of installation I chose "Multiple server install with MAAS"

Entire installation was very well executed.

Now I have a master Cluster with Accepted status. It has two interfaces: eth0 and eth0-ipv6-82309.

To edit the eth0 I see that he's selected Management "Unmanaged"

According to the documentation here so include other computers I need to change to DHCP and DNS. My problem is that if I do that it will conflict with my current rotiador.

Is there any way to do this or can not run on Virtual Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running VirtualBox right now to do testing.  I use this:

```
eth0 (Network 1):  NAT
eth1 (Network 2): Host-network, 10.1.1.1
```

Then I setup eth1 as the managed interface, and boot other VirtualBox machines on the Host-network only interface.  It's been working ok, minus errors I hit with the MAAS system itself.

Setup the Host network in the overall virtualbox preferences.  That sets up a virtual interface on your computer under that 10.1.1.1 IP address.  Then you can communicate with your MAAS server and all the nodes in that subnet.